# elements in arrays printed first -javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have an array and I want to make a `foreach` but it will print a specific word in that array first and then all the others but I don't know how.

```
var data = [
{
    title: "Cloud's Rest", 
    image: "https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3795/10131087094_c1c0a1c859.jpg",
    body: "blah blah blah"
},
{
    title: "Desert Mesa", 
    image: "img url",
    body: "blah blah blah"
}
]
```

For example, if I want to print the array with the `title: Desert Mesa` object first and then all the other ones.

Comment: How do you plan on choosing the object that will be printed first? In other words, _what would be your search query_?

Comment: data.title.str.includes("Desert Mesa");

Answer (score 1):

```
console.log(data.splice(1,1));//take the second one (index:1) out of the array and log it...
data.forEach(console.log);
```

Simply take one element out of the Array, then iterate over the rest?

Or if you dont know a special index, but rather a name substring:

```
console.log(data.splice(data.findIndex(el=>el.title.includes("Mesa")),1));//take the element with name=="Mesa..." out of the array and log it...
data.forEach(console.log);
```

Comment: +1 for simplicity, although the OP plans on accessing the data differently. Maybe you could edit the answer to show how to get the `splice` index with `data.title.str.includes()`?